# Create user commands in C

Tags: c, function

I'd like to create a program in C where the user can type the commands below and my code can take the values.

For example if the user types:

"create 2,3+4,5"
"moveright 2,3 + 3,4"

For the create command I'd like to get the 4 integers (2,3,4 and 5) and store in a specific set of variables. For the moveright comand I'd like to do the same but to another set of variables.

However I don't know how can I write a code in C that understands that the word "create" means that it should store the following integers to a specific set of variables (and the '+' sing in the middle is also puzzling me)...

I've thought about using switch case but I've read that C doesn't support it.

I'd really appreciate any help, at least about what should I research.

Comment: Do you mean the user type de commands at the command prompt (terminal)? Which OS are you targeting?

Comment: You need to decompose your problem into smaller pieces, and address them individually. You'll find that when you do so, that Google becomes more useful. Start with: *"How do I accept user input in C?"*  The answer is likely `scanf()`. Then, *"How do I compare strings in C?"* The answer is `strcmp()`. And so on.

Comment: Dear Jonathan, you're right. I believe strcmp will be useful in this case.

Dear Fpiette, yes it's in the console, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You have to create a new program named `create` and another one named `moveright`. Then the user can type the command lines like `create 2,3+4,5`. Your program named `create` will receive the argument type on the command line after the program name. But be aware that the shell (The programs that read the command line and execute commands or invoke other programs has reserved a lot for characters for special purpose. This means that you'll run into troubles to do that from the command line.

Comment: Another possibility is to create a single program that read lines from the console (Using fgets for example) and parse that command line for the keyword you want it to recognize (create, moveright) and parse the rest of the line for the arguments. Actually you'll write a kind of command interpreter. This time you'll get all control over the entire command lines the user will type. That's a lot of work for someone learning C or programming in general. You should start your learning by something simpler.

Comment: Thanks Fpiette, I'll take a look on the two approaches. If you have any recommendation of tutorial or any link useful it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you want to define a grammar and a parser for it. So, edit your question and define what every command should do. You could use [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form).

Comment: It is much simpler to use a lexer like http://re2c.org/.

Answer (score 2):

To get user input while the program is running you can use the [I/O functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) found in the standard library. Getting user input with [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), and then parsing it with [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) is a common, robust method. Alternatively, depending on complexity, you may want to manually parse the string to get the information you need - the [string library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) has several useful functions to aid in this.

The second argument of the [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) function is a set of strings passed to the program on startup, which could be useful if you want to write a simple program that does a small amount of work per run. You will need to make this data persist between each running of your program. One way is for the data to be [stored in a file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) and [retrieved each time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) using standard file functions.

C absolutely has a [switch statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/switch), albeit for integer constant expressions only.

---

With all that said, your intent is very unclear - from your description it sounds like you're not even sure what your program will actually do. If you don't know what your program will do, how will you write it?

You should start with simpler problems, and build up to something like this.

Here's a set of programs to write that increase in difficulty:

1. Display a simple message to the user.
2. Ask a user for their name, and display a greeting to them personally.
3. Repeatedly read two numbers separated by a space and display their product.
4. Fill an [*array*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) with numerical user input. Ask the user for an operator (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`), and display the reduction of that array using the operator.
5. Take user input to fill an [*array*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) of [*structures*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct) with names and ages (one entry per line, separated by a space, e.g., `Alice 26`). Display the youngest and oldest person's name and age.
6. Ask the user for a comma-separated set of names (e.g., `Alice,Bob,...`).

   - Parse this input string, storing each name in an array.
   - Ask the user for a name.
   - [Search the array for this name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), and if found display the sum of the values of the letters in that name (`a` or `A` is `1`, etc.).

If you can complete these six programs, then you will have a *basic understanding* of the *minimum* amount of skills required to write your goal program, which is essentially an [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)).